# Duplicate documents getting inserted in edge collection

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I am using node driver version 6 of arangodb to insert relations between two vertices as follows.

```
db.collection("starks").save({ 
    _from: "Starks/Lyanna-Stark", 
    _to: "Starks/Ned-Stark", 
    type: "married" 
});
```

This inserts relation `married` between `Starks/Lyanna-Stark` and `Starks/Ned-Stark` into the database. But when I run this query twice, it is inserting it two times with different relation key. I want to avoid this as only one entry should be present for a single relation. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create a unique index for all the relations that you are creating. For example, if the name of your relation collection is `relations`, then run this query to make the combination of `"_from"`, `"_to"`, `"type"` as unique

```
db.relations.ensureIndex({ 
    type: "persistent", 
    fields: [ "_from", "_to", "type" ], 
    unique: true 
});
```

Here is the link for reference https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/index-and-search/indexing/index-basics/#ensuring-uniqueness-of-relations-in-edge-collections

Comment: Just a fix, if the collection name is ```relations``` then query should also be ```db.relations.ensureIndex({ ... }); ```
:P

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem for the simple fact that Arango is creating a new ID for everytime you save the object. The uniqueness of an edge record is achieved by the "_key" key.

In order to do so, you can either provide the "_key" key yourself, or you can alter the logic of your code to check if the record is already present in the db or not.